# Maven Sonar Plugin error: File can't be indexed twice

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I have troubles setting up a SonarQube analysis with maven in our Java project with multiple modules. I have few knowledge in maven and sonar.

Our project structure:

```
parent-module
|-- module-1
|   |-- src
|   |   |-- main
|   |   |-- test
|   |-- pom.xml
|
|-- module-2
|   |-- src
|   |   |-- main
|   |   |-- test
|   |-- pom.xml
|
|-- module-3
|   |-- src
|   |   |-- main
|   |   |-- test
|   |-- pom.xml
|
|-- module-4
|   |-- src
|   |   |-- main
|   |   |-- test
|   |-- pom.xml
|-- pom.xml
```

I added this profile to the settings.xml:

```
<profile>
    <id>sonar</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <!-- Optional URL to server. Default value is http://localhost:9000 -->
        <sonar.host.url>
          https://our.server.com:9000
        </sonar.host.url>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

I added these properties to the parent-module pom.xml: (I tried many differnt properties, but these are the properties I have at the moment)

```
<properties>
    <sonar.login>ourLoginKey</sonar.login>
    <sonar.projectName>ourProjectName</sonar.projectName>

    <sonar.modules>module1,module2,module3,module4</sonar.modules>

    <module1.sonar.sources>src/main/java</module1.sonar.sources>
    <module1.sonar.tests>src/test/java</module1.sonar.tests>
    <module1.sonar.projectBaseDir>.</module1.sonar.projectBaseDir>

    <module2.sonar.sources>src/main/java</module2.sonar.sources>
    <module2.sonar.tests>src/test/java</module2.sonar.tests>
    <module2.sonar.projectBaseDir>.</module2.sonar.projectBaseDir>

    <module3.sonar.sources>src/main/java</module3.sonar.sources>
    <module3.sonar.tests>src/test/java</module3.sonar.tests>
    <module3.sonar.projectBaseDir>.</module3.sonar.projectBaseDir>

    <module4.sonar.sources>src/main/java</module4.sonar.sources>
    <module4.sonar.tests>src/test/java</module4.sonar.tests>
    <module4.sonar.projectBaseDir>.</module4.sonar.projectBaseDir>
</properties>
```

I just can't get it to work. Either I got this error message:

> File X can't be indexed twice. Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns
>   produce disjoint sets for main and test files
>   or it tries to search for a module in another module, which is not logical at all.

I hope you can follow me and forgive for my, maybe, silly question.

Comment: Remove all those properties only keep your login key ...start your analysis from root via `mvn clean verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000` (url must be changed of course)...furthermore a profile not necessary can be done simply via command line....

Comment: @khmarbaise this is the kernel of a good answer... :)

Comment: @khmarbaise thank you very much, this simple approach worked. All the sources I have read about multiple modules told me to set property X and/or property Y and so on, but I haven't found anything simple like that... Maybe you want to post that as an answer?